# How do I modify my pygame code to allow for vertical and horizontal movement?

Tags: python, scroll, pygame, 2d

I'm trying to make a game where a sprite moves freely and explores a 2d world (background image), inspired by [xkcd's Click and Drag](https://xkcd.com/1110/)(but with Arrow Keys). I found this code from the youtuber [code.Pylet](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCmKytNcli9AfEat665KqEeA) to be most like what I want:

```
#import math, random,
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

W, H = 513,513
HW, HH =W/2, H/2
AREA = W*H

#initializing display

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption("astral prohjecting horizontally")
FPS = 500


def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT or (event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()



#colours
BLACK = (0, 0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255, 255)
bg = pygame.image.load("stage.png").convert()
bgWidth, bgHeight = bg.get_rect().size

stageWidth = bgWidth*2
stagePosX = 0
startScrollingPosX = HW

circleRadius = 25
circlePosX = circleRadius

playerPosX = circleRadius
playerPosY = 220
playerVelocityX = 0

#stageHeight = bgHeight*2

while True:
    events()
    k=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if k[K_RIGHT]:
        playerVelocityX= 1
    elif k[K_LEFT]:
        playerVelocityX= -1
    else:
        playerVelocityX=0

    playerPosX += playerVelocityX
    if playerPosX > stageWidth-circleRadius:
        playerPosX = stageWidth - circleRadius
    if playerPosX < circleRadius:
        playerPosX = circleRadius
    if playerPosX < startScrollingPosX:
        circlePosX = playerPosX-stageWidth
    elif playerPosX > stageWidth - startScrollingPosX:
        circlePosX = playerPosX-stageWidth + W
    else:
        circlePosX = startScrollingPosX
        stagePosX += -playerVelocityX

    rel_x = stagePosX % bgWidth
    DS.blit(bg,(rel_x - bgWidth,0))
    if rel_x < W:
        DS.blit(bg, (rel_x,0))

    pygame.draw.circle(DS, WHITE, (circlePosX, playerPosY - circleRadius), circleRadius, 0)
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    DS.fill(BLACK)
```

However, it only works when moving from left to right and back, and when I attempt to copy and change all the variables to their vertical versions,the result moves awkwardly and only up and down. viz:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

W, H = 513,513
HW, HH =W/2, H/2
AREA = W*H

#initializing display

CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
pygame.display.set_caption("astral prohjecting horizontally")
FPS = 500


def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT or (event.type==KEYDOWN and event.key==K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()



#colours
BLACK = (0, 0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255, 255)
bg = pygame.image.load("stage.png").convert()
bgWidth, bgHeight = bg.get_rect().size

stageWidth = bgWidth*2
stageHeight = bgHeight*2
stagePosX = 0
stagePosY = 0
startScrollingPosX = HW
startScrollingPosY = HH

circleRadius = 25
circlePosX = circleRadius
circlePosY = circleRadius

playerPosX = circleRadius
playerPosY = circleRadius
#playerPosY = 2308.5
playerVelocityX = 0
playerVelocityY=0


while True:
    events()
    k=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if k[K_RIGHT]:
        playerVelocityX= 1
    elif k[K_LEFT]:
        playerVelocityX= -1
    else:
        playerVelocityX=0

    if k[K_UP]:
        playerVelocityY = -1
    elif k[K_DOWN]:
        playerVelocityY = 1
    else:
        playerVelocityY = 0

    playerPosX += playerVelocityX
    if playerPosX > stageWidth-circleRadius:
        playerPosX = stageWidth - circleRadius
    if playerPosX < circleRadius:
        playerPosX = circleRadius
    if playerPosX < startScrollingPosX:
        circlePosX = playerPosX-stageWidth
    elif playerPosX > stageWidth - startScrollingPosX:
        circlePosX = playerPosX-stageWidth + W
    else:
        circlePosX = startScrollingPosX
        stagePosX += -playerVelocityX

    playerPosY += playerVelocityY
    if playerPosY > stageHeight -circleRadius:
        playerPosY = stageHeight - circleRadius
    if playerPosY < circleRadius:
        playerPosY = circleRadius
    if playerPosY < startScrollingPosY:
        circlePosY = playerPosY - stageHeight
    elif playerPosY > stageHeight - startScrollingPosY:
        circlePosY = playerPosY - stageHeight + H
    else:
        circlePosY = startScrollingPosY
        stagePosY += -playerVelocityY

    rel_x = stagePosX % bgWidth
    DS.blit(bg,(rel_x - bgWidth,0))
    if rel_x < W:
        DS.blit(bg, (rel_x,0))

    rel_y = stagePosY % bgHeight
    DS.blit(bg,(0,(rel_y - bgHeight)))
    if rel_y < H:
        DS.blit(bg,(0, rel_y))
    #stagePosY += 1

    pygame.draw.circle(DS, BLACK, (circlePosX, playerPosY+circleRadius), circleRadius, 0)
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    DS.fill(BLACK)
```

I can't figure out where the error is; Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing blit of an image multiple times at similar coordinates, the images are stacked on top of each-other, so you only see the last one.

Your error comes from not taking care of the combined two dimensions to blit the stage picture.

Here is the blit part that take care of it and also display correctly the 4 images at the corner :

```
rel_x = stagePosX % bgWidth
rel_y = stagePosY % bgHeight
DS.blit(bg,(rel_x - bgWidth,rel_y - bgHeight))

if rel_x < W:
    DS.blit(bg, (rel_x,rel_y - bgHeight))
    if rel_y < H:
        DS.blit(bg,(rel_x, rel_y))

if rel_y < H:
    DS.blit(bg,(rel_x - bgWidth, rel_y))
```